# Maximum Number of Columns in Sqlite in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Actually I am having 11 columns in my Database(Sqlite).Now I am increasing the number of columns to 15.Will it affect my application?If Yes, then what will be the feasible solution?

Comment: The maximum number of columns in the SQLite built into most devices is 2000 (defined @ build time by SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN). So you're not quite there yet.

Comment: Do you have any link where this is described about SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN?

Comment: I got it at [link](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it should not effect on application as long as you have enough memory Check this link here: http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Answer (score 5):

i think it wont.

The default setting for SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN is 2000. You can change it at compile time to values as large as 32767. On the other hand, many experienced database designers will argue that a well-normalized database will never need more than 100 columns in a table.

so in your case 15 would not be an issue i think.

Comment: You can change it at compile time to values as large as 32767. Can you please explain how?

Comment: @user3164187 Find the definition of SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN in the source and change it, or, re-define it. They write the limits "SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN" etc this way for a reason, because this is how they're defined in code.

Answer (score 0):

It wont effect the application .....

Actually If the table grows vertically there will be performance problems...

But there wont be any effect if it grows horizontally....

Any how i prefer you to normalize the tables if there is any possibility...